# How to include tinymce from shared server

Tags: php

I am using this simple PHP script which fetches the shared resources, in this example tiny_mce. How can I extend this script so that it checks if a local copy exists first before fetching the file from the shared resource.

```
<?php
$request = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$url = 'http://shared.domain.co.uk/javascript/' . $request;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$headers = substr($data, 0, strpos($data, "\r\n\r\n"));
$headers = preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $headers);
foreach($headers as $header)
    if(strpos($header, 'Content-') !== false)
        header($header);
$data = substr($data,strpos($data, "\r\n\r\n")+4);
print $data;
?>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you downloading a copy of TinyMCE's javascript with php then dumping it to the page? Why not use `<script src="path/to/tinymce.js" />`

Comment: Honestly I can't remember why we used to do it this way but there was a good reason

Comment: I think you'll find there wasn't a good reason.

Comment: The main reason was so that the resource such as tinymce can be included from an external domain because it very rare it changes. So you can see from my answer that the main advantages of including it via curl is that it will even work with no internet in development environment

Comment: @JohnMagnolia - that makes no sense.  To do that you should just include it via a script tag either locally or on a shared server on the net.

Comment: Because I am lazy and prefer to write the code to work for me. Rather than update the script tag each time each time I move a website from localhost to the live domain.

Comment: @JohnMagnolia No, I think what Toby is saying is use PHP to update the script tag like `<script src="<?php echo get_path_to_tinymce();>" />`. You can conditionally point tinymce to wherever you want without downloading the entire library, piping it through php, and outputting it to the page everytime.

Comment: Back to this discussion, the original developer says it was done this way to get around the cross domain issues with TinyMCE. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How-to_load_TinyMCE_crossdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew there was a reason, although it does run rather slow.

tinyMCE into 2 locations e.g:

**Localhost**

- /www/javascript/resources/tiny_mce

**Shared subdomain**

- /var/www/domain.co.uk/subdomains/shared/public/javascript/resources/tiny_mce

.php
small php script to be included with each project that uses tinymce e.g: "domain.co.uk/webapp/shared/javascript/resources/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"

```
<?php
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$request = substr($request, strpos($request, 'javascript/resources/')+21);

$domain = 'shared.domain.co.uk';
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'sandbox.') !== false) {
    $domain = 'sandbox.domain.co.uk';
} elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'localhost') !== false || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '127.0.0.1') !== false) {
    $domain = 'localhost';
} 

$url = 'http://'.$domain.'/javascript/resources/' . $request;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$headers = substr($data, 0, strpos($data, "\r\n\r\n"));
$headers = preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $headers);
foreach($headers as $header)
    if(strpos($header, 'Content-') !== false)
        header($header);
$data = substr($data,strpos($data, "\r\n\r\n")+4);
print $data;
?>
```

Then a .htaccess script to rewrite anything after "resources" in: domain.co.uk/webapp/shared/javascript/resources

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: Can't believe they chose this over my answer :)

Comment: Because your simple answer doesn't work with TinyMCE on a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variable paths that depend whether it is development or not, why not decalre a variable that holds the base path?

```
if($is_development){
    $base = 'http://localhost/js/';
}else{
    $base = 'http://domain.com/js/'
}

<script src="<?=$base;?>tinymce.js"></a>
```